# Skip redirect via localhost in React router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have list of links but I see that every link is redirected via `localhost`:

[image]

Source code:

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.links')}>
  <Typography variant="body1" component="p" gutterBottom>
    {component?.external_links?.map((link, index) => (
      <li style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }} key={index}>
        <a href={link.toString()}>{link.toString()}</a>
      </li>
    ))}
  </Typography>
</DetailsBox>
```

Anyone can advice how to skip the redirection? I just want to go for example to `www.ww.pl`

Comment: I had similar problem. I added `onClick` event which handles stopping event propagation further. Code is `onClick = {(e) => {e.preventDefault()}`

Comment: as I said in my comment the link string has to start with prefix of `http` or `https` you can create the href as ` `//${link.toString()}` ` (wrap the code in `)

Comment: Having your code `<a href={`//${link.toString()}`}>{link.toString()}</a>` links redirects to 'https//www.ww2.pl'. Lack of colon after `https` ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link have to start either with `http://` or `https://` or just `//` (which will take or http/s itself), otherwise its translated as route and not separate page.

the link should be either stored with `http://` or `https://`
or you have to do it yours

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.links')}>
  <Typography variant="body1" component="p" gutterBottom>
    {component?.external_links?.map((link, index) => (
      <li style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }} key={index}>
        <a href={`//${link.toString()}`}>{link.toString()}</a>
      </li>
    ))}
  </Typography>
</DetailsBox>
```

Comment: Hmmm I understand the idea but I do not want to involve end user with understanding those details how to write a link, end user wants to just write a link without those details. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: if the links are by user, than you have to run them true sanitization function, which will check if they have the correct begining and if not, you have to edit the string on FE by yourself